# Windows 7 Installation asks for AHCI drivers when installed a HDD into the DVD Bay

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, installation, drivers, ahci

I'm facing a problem I never faced before: I replaced the DVD Optical Drive of my laptop with a HDD. The HDD is correctly seen into the BIOS but when I'm trying to install Windows 7 the Installation is asking for AHCI drivers.

How should I manage this issue?

Comment: You can either provide the drivers or disable AHCI within the BIOS.

Comment: I have an SSD so AHCI is quite mandatory.
I don't have any AHCI drivers provided with myu laptop.

@Ramhound

Comment: If you have a ssd then you had to provide drivers

Comment: Thanks for your support @Ramhound but I don't have any AHCI drivers provided with my laptop or with my SSD. I have just the migration tool. Where should I download the AHCI drivers?

Comment: The website where your other drivers for your laptop are located

Comment: They're not available [there](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N53SV/HelpDesk_Download/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Asus page is not providing the AHCI drivers for the Optical Drive Sata Slot.

I've just used the ones available [here](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS028984) (my laptop is an Asus N53SV) and the installation just started as expected.